# how do you estimate irt parameters if Theta and response is given?

Tags: r, item-response-theory

I have good Theta estimates for people (from an already existing test). These people have also answered a few (2-5) untried experimental items. How can I get the a,b params for these new items given the response (on these new items) and Theta using R?

Comment: You probably want to reconsider that approach. Using point estimates for the latent traits is not as effective as including all the items in the model at once (precision of the values is not accounted for). Therefore it will make a difference which prediction method you used to obtain the estimates (EAP, MAP, ML, etc).

Comment: Thanks for the response.
Here is my situation:
I have already calibrated an item bank and now I will use those items in an adaptive test - so the response matrix will be very sparse. I was hoping that I can calibrate new experimental items using only the Theta from the adaptive test and will not have to include the response data I used to calibrate the item bank.

From your answer it seems that its best to use the whole response set.

Comment: Yes, use the full response set. The fact that there is missingness by design really doesn't matter if you use a full-information estimator (like MML). It's also possible to fix the previously estimated parameters are their starting values so that only the new item parameters will be estimated (would reduce parameter space by quite a bit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using point estimates for the latent traits is not as effective as including all the items in the model at once (precision of the values is not accounted for). Therefore it will make a difference which prediction method you used to obtain the estimates (EAP, MAP, ML, etc).

The fact that there is missingness by design really doesn't matter if you use a full-information estimator (like MML) which assume the missing values are MAR. Therefore, using the full response set is probably the most optimal and unbiased approach. It's also possible to fix the previously estimated parameters are their starting values so that only the new item parameters will be estimated (and would reduce parameter space by quite a bit for longer tests).